# How can I make Aptana/Eclipse replace selected text with quotes?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

When selecting a portion of text in Aptana Studio (I assume the same is true for Eclipse in general) like so:
[image]
And then typing a single quotation mark (`"`), it will result in this:
[image]

---

But what I want is this:
[image]
Or **even better**:
[image]

Please note, I really like automatic closing of parenthesis/quotation marks/braces/..., I just want to affect the behavior when text is selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In Aptana Studio 3:

Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > Disable "Wrap selected text with matching characters"

[image]

This helped me find the solution: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/1122-disable-automatically-closing-quotes

Comment: But that completely disables auto-closing of quotation marks, which isn't what I want. Or am I missing something?

Comment: i don't know what you are doing, but when i **disable "wrap selected text with matching characters"**, then the problem you described is solved for me. don't be confused by the linked page, they are doing another thing but it's the same preferences menu page in aptana

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could.  That's an annoying feature, IMHO.